# How to disable specific dates in Magento Order Delivery Date extensions calendar

Tags: javascript, magento, calendar

I want to disable specific dates in Magento Connect Order Delivery Date Calendar and tried many ways. But could not be successful. Below is my code. It says "TypeError: $.inArray is not a function" when click on the calendar icon.

```
disableFunc : function(date)
        { 
            var day_off_array = dayoff.split(",") ;

            currentTime = new Date();
            var d1=currentTime.getDate();
            var m1=currentTime.getMonth();
            var y1=currentTime.getFullYear();
            m1=m1+1;

            var counter = 1;
    var disabledDays = 
                       ["10-20-2013", "10-21-2013", "11-15-2013", "11-17-2013"];

    var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
    if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1) {
    return [false];
    }
    }
    return [true];



            if(y < y1)
                {
                return true;
            }
            else if(m1 > m && y==y1)
                {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

and this is the original code.

```
disableFunc : function(date)
        {  
            var y = calendar.date.getFullYear();
            var m = calendar.date.getMonth();     
            var d = calendar.date.getDate();

            var day_off_array = dayoff.split(",") ;
            //document.write(day_off_array);
            currentTime = new Date();
            var d1=currentTime.getDate();
            var m1=currentTime.getMonth();
            var y1=currentTime.getFullYear();
            var counter = 1;
            for (var i=0; i<day_off_array.length;i++){
                if (day_off_array[i]>=0 && day_off_array[i]!=''){
                    if (date.getDay()==day_off_array[i]){
                        if (date.getDate()==currentTime.getDate()){
                            test_flag=true;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(y < y1)
                {
                return true;
            }
            else if(m1 > m && y==y1)
                {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure $ is the object, try using jQuery instead ?

Comment: @SKV i tried after putting this question on this. Then the error did not appear. But this did not work.

Comment: that means jQuery is the object then you should check arrays values are properly inserted or not.. try alerting array contents

Answer (score 1):

It's too late to answer the question, but this may help someone like me!

```
var disabledDays = ["10-20-2014", "10-21-2014", "11-15-2014", "11-17-2014"];

var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
    var dd = (m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y;
    if(disabledDays.indexOf(dd) != -1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```